# How to control the pencil in gimp

Tags: gimp, script-fu

I'm writing a script in gimp and I want to place several random points on the screen. I placed in my (python) script the two following lines

```
gimp.pdb.gimp_context_set_brush_size(5.0)
gimp.pdb.gimp_pencil(drawable,2,p)
```

But this didn't have the desired effect, or any effect.

Also, I don't know how to set the brush (the small icon next to the brush size in the gui).

Finally, is there a way to get a list of pencil dots on the current layer?

Comment: You might want to re-tag this question as python-fu not script-fu, since you are not actually using script-fu.

Comment: @ZachStark but the commands are virtually the same.